# uniform quantizer for sine wave with amplitude -1 db

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

i have a signal sine wave with an amplitude of -1 db 
The quantizer step Δ is 1/7. The middle quantization level is 0 and the other levels are ±kΔ,, k=1-7. the output is 4-bit unsigned integer which values from 0 to 14 corresponding to the 15 quantization levels. 
how i can calculate the 4 bit output

Comment: please provide the [Minimal working Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and you can please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to get the answer for your question.

Comment: This sounds like it might be a more appropriate question for the Electrical Engineering site: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ .  It would also help to clarify your question a little bit; I'm an EE professor and am having trouble making sense of what you're asking.

Comment: hello sir , like i said i have signal sine wave signal = AM*sin(2*pi*f*nT); 
with an amplitude of -1 db , i want to do a quantizer that have 15 level  ,and 0 is the middle level the quantizer step is delta=0.14 the other levels are ±kΔ, where k=-6, the output is 4 bit  , how i can create the quantizer in matlab